# Modal form changing color when clicked on parent

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, modal-dialog

I would like to change color of textBox in modal form when I click its parent form/control. 
I tried events on modal child as Activated, Enter but nothing is called when I click parent, only tray bar for modal form blinked.

Is there any way how to get information, that user clicked on parent and than change color of textbox in modal form?

I am using c# and winforms, thanks a lot!

Comment: When you use `.ShowDialog()` method, you can't click on parent window anymore until you close modal dialog. this means that parent window never receive any `Click` event

Comment: Actually, you can click on parent, but its pointless :) I dont need any parent interaction - I was hoping for any event in child form called when you click on parent - something like focus or whatever

Answer (score 0):

By design, a modal dialog will not let you interact with the parent.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a modal form displayed you can't focus any other form or controls on those forms in same process. That is what modal forms are designed for, to keep users focus on new form, and continue using other form when (s)he dismisses the modal one.

I can suggest alternative approach:

- show child form mode-less
- set `Owner` property of child form to calling form
- disable controls on calling form which you want disabled, while other form is displayed
- once child form is closed, re-enable disabled controls

Comment: Problem is that I have modal with formBorderStyle set to none - so its not so visible and when user click on parent form - it doesnt work - because he didnt close modal child - I need to let him to know that modal is steel opened